# Export to excel file problem with displaying information

Tags: soql, contact, data-export, excel

Following is my page

```
<apex:page controller="contactquery" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" cache="true">
<apex:pageBlock title="Export Results" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cs}" var="contact">
        <apex:column value="{!contact.ID}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!contact.phone}"/>   
    </apex:pageBlockTable>    
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="account">                    
        <apex:column value="{!account.id}"/>              
        <apex:column value="{!account.name}"/>            
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

And following is my controller

```
public class contactquery{
public List<Contact> cs{get; set;}
public List<Account> acc{get; set;}    
public contactquery()
{
cs = new List<Contact>();
acc = new List<Account>();     
   for (Account a : [Select id, Name,(Select id, Name from Contacts) from Account])   
   {
     acc.add(a);
   } 
 }
 }
```

I get an excel sheet for accounts only.

**PROBLEM:** Unable to display contacts related to every account in a separate column. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Following is the required sample excel(without borders).[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing? Populating `cs` list?

Comment: The excel sheet displays only account information. My problem is that I'm unable to display contacts in a separate column in the same excel sheet.

Comment: Can you detail exactly what you want to see? An Account can have many Contacts - do you e.g. want the Account information duplicating for each of them or something else?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. Let me update my question with a similar screenshot workbench...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
        <apex:column value="{!a.ID}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
        <apex:column>
         <apex:dataTable value="{!a.contacts}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.id}"/>                          
            <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>              
            <apex:column value="{!c.phone}"/> 
         </apex:dataTable>
        </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: Glad it helped.your welcome!

Comment: The one thing I'd suggest is using apex:dataTable instead of pageBlockTable. You're downloading a lot of extra stuff with pageBlockTable that is unused in Excel (class attributes, event handlers, etc.). With my simple example of some 20 accounts, my file size with dataTable is 19k, versus 37k for pageBlockTable...almost double the size. You're also forcing the VF page renderer to do more work.

Comment: Hi @Peter! I realized that as soon as you posted :). Thanks

Comment: snehakem, not too late to edit your answer... :-)

Comment: Thanks again @Peter.you read my mind :).i was bit hesitated,thought you would have that pleasure :P